# How to store binary data in MySQL

Tags: mysql, binary, data-storage

How do I store binary data in a MySQL database?

Comment: Please update your question to include details of what you want to achieve (or what you tried and it failed). A simple search gives me how to store and retrieve binary data from a database.

Comment: Please update your question. There is no details on what you are trying to do or what you have done so far.

Comment: why is this not a duplicate?

Answer (score 16):

This question is not so straight forward to answer, as it sounds: There are lots of different binary data usage patterns out there, each with their own caveats and pros and cons. Let me try to summarize:

- Short pieces of binary data, such as password hashes, work very well by simply base64-encoding them and storing the resulting string as a VARCHAR
- "Not-quite-binary" data, such as document snipplets with the occasional non-printable can be escaped and sored as a string
- The BLOB datatype allows you to store arbitrary chunks of binary data, but I strongly recommend against using it: Store the data in a file, then store the path to the file in a String type. You gain nothing from storing binary data, that the DB doesn't "understand" in the DB.

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest `LONGBLOB` for storing files in `MySQL`.
It all depends on what kind of binary and your application.

```
TINYBLOB - A BLOB column with a maximum length of 255 (2^8 - 1) characters.
BLOB - A BLOB column with a maximum length of 65,535 (2^16 - 1) characters.
MEDIUMBLOB - A BLOB column with a maximum length of 16,777,215 (2^24 - 1) characters.
LONGBLOB - A BLOB column with a maximum length of 4,294,967,295 (2^32 - 1) characters.
```

Answer (score 2):

Binary data can be stored in a MySQL database in a [BLOB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/blob.html) field. 
A [BLOB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/blob.html) is a binary large object that can hold a variable amount of data.