# Store numpy array in MySQL (reloaded)

Tags: python, mysql, numpy, pickle

This is going to be a duplicate of
[store numpy array in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30713062/store-numpy-array-in-mysql) . The reason is that the *actual* question is not answered there, and 5 years later I (another random person) am struggling with the same problem.

#### Goal

I have a lot of numpy vectors. I want to store each of them in a BLOB column in a MySQL database. [I have already read that this is likely not a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10979193/1360979), but I'd like to do it anyway. For this, I am trying to create a query. The code looks something like:

```py
query = 'INSERT INTO vectors_table (word_id, vector) VALUES '

for i in vectors:
    query += ({}, {}).format(i.index, i.vector.dumps())
```

(notice the call to `.dumps()`)

#### Alternatives

Numpy arrays have a few options of functions to "serialize" its data:

- `.dumps()` gives me a `bytes` "string";
- `.tostring()` also gives me a `bytes` "string", [but apparently has problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30169429)

I could also use Pickle. There is a function called `pickle.dumps` that also gives me a `bytes` sequence.

#### Problem

When I try creating the query, it inserts that goddamn `b` before the string. E.g., if I print one of my vectors, it looks like:

```
b'\x80\x02cnumpy.core.multiarray\n_reconstruct\nq\x00cnumpy\nndarray\nq\x01K\x00\x85q\x02c_codecs\nencode\nq\x03X\x01\x00\x00\x00bq\x04X\x06\x00\x00\x00latin1q\x05\x86q\x06Rq\x07\x87q\x08Rq\t(K\x01M\x00\x0c\x85q\ncnumpy\ndtype\nq\x0bX\x02\x00\x00\x00f4q\x0cK\x00K\x01\x87q\rRq\x0e(K\x03X\x01\x00\ ...
```

Unfortunately, as can be seen in the "Alternatives" above, this is true for all alternatives I have found so far.

#### Attempted solutions

In trying to solve the problem, I find lots of people telling me to use [`decode`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-string), or to [cast the bytes into a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31058055/how-do-i-convert-a-python-3-byte-string-variable-into-a-regular-string/31060836).

Calling either `.decode('ascii')` or `.decode('utf-8')` has led to [`UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21129020/how-to-fix-unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte?rq=1) and `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte`, respectively.

Trying to convert the `bytes` into a string creates a string that includes the "b".

#### Is there any better way of doing this?

I am noob with MySQL and totally believe that I am missing some obvious solution. I am getting to the point where I'm planning to just create a string with

```py
for i in vectors:
    old_str = str(i.vector.dumps())
    new_str = old_str[1:]
    query += ({}, {}).format(i.index, new_str)
```

And just insert that into my query string. Stil... I can't believe that this is the only way to get this to work.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, the answer to my question was [in this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15504301/1360979). I'll answer it here in case someone else has a similar problem.

I was doing

```py
query = 'INSERT INTO vectors_table (word_id, vector) VALUES '

for i in vectors:
    query += "({}, {})".format(i.index, i.vector.dumps())
```

and then running `cursor.execute(query)`.

Instead, what I should do was to write my query with `%s`:

```py
query = 'INSERT INTO vectors_table (word_id, vector) VALUES (%s, %s)'
```

then get all the elements I want to insert into the table:

```py
tuples = [(i.index, i.vector.dumps()) for i in vectors]
```

and let the MySQL library handle the escaping of the bad bytes:

```py
cursor.executemany(query, tuples)
```